# Running tests in parallel in saucelabs slows down at the end

Tags: java, gradle, junit, saucelabs

I am running JUnit Selenium tests on Saucelabs via TeamCity in parallel. I have 4 concurrent sessions available and 125 tests. When I run the build everything seems fine at the beginning. There are 4 tests ran concurrently. But around the 90th test the concurrent sessions become 3 then two and the last 5 or so are ran 1 by 1.

I've tried to increase the number of maxParallelForks to 6 hoping this will compensate for the slow down but now Saucelabs complain about misconfigured tests and wants me to upgrade my plan.

This is what I have in build.gradle

```
include `<my_tests_packages>`
maxParallelForks = 4
```

My TeamCity builds just run
`clean test`

Has anyone encountered such problem. I am expecting all 4 sessions to be used while there are at least 4 more tests.

EDIT:
Each class has only one @Test in it.
Unfortunately, I am forced to use Gradle instead of Maven.

Comment: It depends on how your test code is structured. Gradle can only run in parallel at the Class level, not the method/test level, so if you have one class with more tests that take longer to run, it will still be executing after the other classes have finished. Additionally, unfortunately, with Gradle you are restricted in setting maxParallelForks by the number of processors in your CI server. Maven with the surefire plugin allows for a lot more fine tuned configuration for running in parallel without the same limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About how long do your tests execute before this happens?

A Sauce Labs browser VM can slow down and become unstable after more than 30 minutes total execution time.  The way to prevent this is to use a new browser session for each test.

Also, what is the memory usage on your system?  If you are forking JVMs and not cleaning them up you could be running into maximum memory available or swapping.